# Changing the Multiple Polyline stroke color on google map v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I need to create multiple polylines ,each with its own color, and their markers are connected to each other,I am using google map v3.

For example,I have five markers and they are all the connected to each other through red color polylines. Now I want to show this red color polyline in multiple color schemes, first polyline in green, second in Blue, third in Black and so on.

Here is my code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var poly;
var map;
var path;
var i = parseInt(0, 10);
var marker;          

function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.879535, -87.624333);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
  var polyOptions = {
    strokeColor: '#000000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  }
  poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
  poly.setMap(map);
  // Add a listener for the click event
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addLatLng);
}

/**
* Handles click events on a map, and adds a new point to the Polyline.
* @param {MouseEvent} mouseEvent
*/
function addLatLng(event) {
  i++;
  //var path = poly.getPath();
  path = poly.getPath();
  var polyOptions2 = {
    strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 3
  }
  if (i == 2) {
    poly.setOptions(polyOptions2);

  }
  else {
    polyOptions2.strokeColor = "#FF0000";
    poly.setOptions(polyOptions2);
  }
  path.push(event.latLng);
  // Add a new marker at the new plotted point on the polyline.
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: event.latLng,
    title: '#' + path.getLength(),
    map: map
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Load your marker options and color for the polylines into an json array and loop through them creating the markers and polylines.

Hope this gets you going.

Answer (score 2):

set this portion of your code in for loop like

```
       var colorVariable = ["red","green","blue","yellow","black"];

        for(var a =0;a<=5;a++){
              var polyOptions = {
                strokeColor: colorVariable[a],
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
              }
              poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
              poly.setMap(map);
        }
```

It will work fine

Comment: Yes, Thank you .